# Get all method names starting with a substring from a PHP object

Tags: php, class, oop, object

I have an object and want a method that returns how much method this Object have that start with `bla_`.

I found `get_class_methods()` which returns all method names, but I only want names which starts with `bla_`

Answer (score 49, accepted):

You can use [`preg_grep()`](http://de.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-grep.php) to filter them:

```
$method_names = preg_grep('/^bla_/', get_class_methods($object));
```

Comment: From where the variable `$object` comes?
Actually I want to fetch method list of 4 and 5 controllers. How I can set the `$object` variable?

Comment: `$object` is the class name as a string or an instance of the class, ([as indicated in the documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.get-class-methods.php)).

Answer (score 6):

Try:

```
$methods = array();
foreach (get_class_methods($myObj) as $method) {
    if (strpos($method, "bla_") === 0) {
        $methods[] = $method;
    }
}
```

Note that `===` is necessary here. `==` won't work, since `strpos()` returns `false` if no match was found. Due to PHPs dynamic typing this is equal to `0` and therefore a strict (type safe) equality check is needed.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just make your own function that loops through the array from get_class_methods() and tests each element against "bla_" and returns a new list with each matching value?

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest something a bit more flexible such as this (unless the method names are dynamic or are unknown):

```
interface ITest
{
    function blah_test();
    function blah_test2();
}

class Class1 implements ITest
{
    function blah_test()
    {
    }

    function blah_test2()
    {
    }

    function somethingelse()
    {
    }
}

$obj = new Class1();

$methods = array_intersect( get_class_methods($obj), get_class_methods('ITest') );
foreach( $methods as $methodName )
{
    echo "$methodName\n";
}
```

Outputs:

```
blah_test
blah_test2
```