# How do I get the function name outside a function in PHP?

Tags: php, function

Is this possible?

Pseudo-code:

```
class MyClass
{
  function myFunc1()
  {
     ...
  }
  function myFunc2()
  {
    echo GET_FUNCTION_NAME($this->myFunc1)
  }
}
```

Wanted output:

```
myFunc1
```

In the code above the `GET_FUNCTION_NAME` method/function/construct/whatever would give back the textual representation of the function name given as parameter.

So the main point would be to get the **name of a function** as a string from **outside** the function.

All the code I have found deals with giving a function name via a string (eg. specifying callback methods), but none of them mentions how to **get that function name without manually writing it in a string** (thus duplicating code in a string and making refactoring harder than needed).
OTOH from inside the function it is easy with eg. `__FUNCTION__` variable, so I'm not looking for that.

**EDIT**

A typical use case would be any callback method.
One example where I confronted this problem is the [set_error_handler()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php) method where it awaits a [`callable`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.callable.php) as first parameter. The `callable` can be simplified as a `string`. The problem is that if I specify the function name as a string, any time in the future when I will do refactoring I will have to take extra care to search for the strings as well and do special handling of them otherwise wrong references will be left there.
Not to mention the principle that any name should be defined once and any other use should refer to that one.

Comment: Check this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1826503/php-get-all-method-names-from-an-object-with-name-bla

Comment: Agreed, I can't begin to imagine what the use case for this is? What are you actually trying to achieve here? What are you going to do with the name once you receive it?

Comment: This smells like an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/)

Comment: in case you really really need that - why don't you `echo "myFunc1"` ?

Comment: @B001ᛦ I think the point was to get it "without manually writing it in a string", as per the question wording

Comment: @ADyson Agree, but the current code doesn't match to the question wording `echo GET_FUNCTION_NAME($this->myFunc1)`

Comment: @B001ᛦ what do you mean? The code shown is a psuedo-code representation of a theoretical idea - i.e. how to get a string representing the name of a function, without using a hard-coded string as the return value, and without executing the function in question and relying on `__FUNCTION__`. I see no contradiction between that and the pseudo-code. Can you clarify your concern?

Comment: Sorry, I was writing an answer, but Machavity blocked my answer. This happens more often than I like, and really makes me rethink whether I should write any answers.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware Rather than complaining in comments, why not ping and explain how this isn't a duplicate? You can always ping dupehammers, even if their name doesn't appear in the autocomplete

Comment: @Machavity I don't know how to "ping". Is that simply using "@". I've done that before without any success ever, I'm sure you're also convinced you're right. I used the "reopen" option of this question. Why is the duplicate you selected not the right one? The question is about a specific method, not about listing all public functions. Anyway, it doesn't seem that the SO cares one way or another.

Comment: I made an edit and tried to clarify the use case for which I am searching a solution.
@Machavity Using reflection is not a solution as long as I have to type the function name in a string, so this is not a duplicate.
As ADyson mentioned the main point is circumventing the string usage.

Comment: Could you make use of anonymous functions instead? Is using the string form of callable critical for some reason?

Comment: @KIKOSoftware would you mind taking another go at answering my question?

Comment: @CollinD Well, putting the function in a closure could work but it would produce an unreadable mess (the function is kinda big) which wouldn't be really smaller mess if I'd put only a forwarder function call into the anonymous function.

As I wrote previously the string form leads to hardly maintainable code which I would like to avoid. So it's not critical but painful, I was hoping for some elegant solution to this problem.

Answer (score 2):

If the problem is that You need to specify a callback not using a string, but the function symbol itself, You can do with a help of anonymous function:

```
class MyClass {

    function call(callable $c) {
        ...
    }

    function mycallback() {
        ...
    }

    function dosomejob() {
        $this->call(function() { $this->mycallback(); })
    }
}
```

From point of view of Your refactoring tool, there's still call to function `mycallback`, it's not reffered as a string.

Comment: Thank you for the post, but as I already wrote in a comment to the original question, using a forwarder (anonymous) function still leads to a quite messy code. I upvote it as it is possibly the most usable workaround, but it is still just a workaround, not a proper solution.

Comment: @Tylla Thank You, I missed Your comment to the original question (until now). I am afraid that the most readable PHP can do is PHP 7.4's `fn() => $this->mycallback()`. It would be nice if there was something like `MyClass::class` for functions, but unforunately there's not.